# Crystal Reports takes hours to export to pdf by code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I´m facing this issue a long time, after months i´m still not able to find any solution. Here´s the scenario:
VS 2019, Framework 4.6 and Crystal reports 13_0_27.

The  following code takes hours to export a pdf (about 400 pages and 30.000 rows) . If i open the report
with crystal reports and export the document, same query by code, only takes seconds.

I tried a couple things, like ExportToStream and save the stream to file, or exporting direcly to disk
and other post did read that "pdfFormatOptions.UsePageRange = True" should help, but same result.

The code works fine with smalls pdfs with, for example, 100 rows.

```
Informe.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\informes\report.rpt");

        for (i = 0; i < Informe.Database.Tables.Count; ++i)
        {
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "Server";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "BBDD";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "user";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "user";
            Informe.Database.Tables[i].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
        }

        diskOpts.DiskFileName = PDFPath + _cabe.Guid + "_minutos.pdf";
        ExportOptions exportOpts2 = Informe.ExportOptions;
        exportOpts2.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;
        exportOpts2.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        exportOpts2.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        
        try
        {
            Informe.RecordSelectionFormula = @" {CabeceraFacturas.Guid}='{" + _cabe.Guid.ToString() + "}'";
            //Informe.Export();
            Stream oStream;
            oStream = (Stream)Informe.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(RutaGeneracionPDF + _cabe.Guid + "_minutos.pdf", (int)oStream.Length))
            {
                byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[oStream.Length];
                oStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
            }


        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How large is the resulting file?

Comment: When you stepped through the code, which lines of code were slow?

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms226447(v=vs.90) style code go faster?

Comment: The result file is about 1.5Mb

Comment: This one is where the code stops : oStream = (Stream)Informe.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat) or Informe.Export(); if i export directly to disk

Comment: I don´t see any differences between this code and mine besides set de ExportOptions within Export method and the different output file format. I already tried to export to excel and same result.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first i tried before change to ExportToStream

Comment: Can you make a sanitized (remove sensitive info) rpt with saved data available so I can test the export to pdf using my code?  Perhaps I can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After expending days and hours and headaches i finally did the trick.

in each detail (About 30.000 rows) i had a formula wich calculated some value with two fields of the detail and two from a joined view. the view was the problem when i was exporting by code (Exporting within Crystal Reports worked ok with no delay). I had to create a new table in SQL, inserting all the rows in view in this new table and add this table to report and ..voilá, it worked, exported report in seconds.